# Probably a moth larvae but better to confirm

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I know,

It reacts to light

the red seems to be blood but can't say for sure

1 to 10 mm

it has a casing of something soft fabric possibly

it grabs to walls

Comment: That's what I thought, but I still have some doubt because it only has one black spot.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a larvae of *Tinea pellionella*, the case-bearing clothes moth.
*T. pellionella* is a species of tineoid moth in the family Tineidae (i.e. the fungus moths).
[image: JMK, CC BY-SA 4.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0, via Wikimedia Commons]